# Diaporama in c#

Tags: c#, image

I have this code:

```
public diapo()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DispatcherTimer messageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    messageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(messageTimer_Tick);
    messageTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    messageTimer.Start();
}

private void source1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files(*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

    string sC = (openFileDialog.FileName);
}

private void source2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog2 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog2.Filter = "Image files(*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

    string sB = (openFileDialog2.FileName);
}

private void source3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog3 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog3.Filter = "Image files(*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

    string sA = (openFileDialog3.FileName);
}
```

I want to it switch pic.source (which is a image) every 3 seconds to the next string so sA, sB, sC

Comment: You variable `sA`, `sB`, etc. have a scope issue they do not exist in the form. They will be destroy at the end of each method. Add a `List<string> paths` at the class level and use the Add method.

Comment: There is no question here... Which part are you having trouble with? what is not working?

Comment: Also note that all 3 of your `sourceX` methods are identical... Which leads me to conclude that you have little knowledge of the purpose of a method (avoid having to write the same thing at multiple places). Moreover, parenthesis around `openFileDialog.FileName` aren't actually needed, not sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: Well, that'll be in your messateTimer_Tick method which you're not sharing.